# xcode doesn't show my plist file that has more than 15k lines

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I have a plist that has more than 15k lines, that I generate through my python script. If I limit it to 100 lines, xcode opens the plist without any error, but if I open the 15k+ plist xcode says:

```
The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format
```

So does xcode has a limit on plist files with a large number of lines? Else I cant explain why this error comes on only the big number file..

Comment: That's a overly large plist file. Consider using a database. Think about how much memory is being used to load (and parse) such a large xml file.

Comment: You are right and I will consider this. Atm that plist is just for the launch important..

Comment: Plist it's not XML in release build - you can make it binary - so it's the right way to keep data - if he needs to load them all at once. If you are doing some searches / selections - than database is the way to go.

Comment: Are you sure that your file is in correct format? So, there is no bugs in your python script?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think i'll go the database way. Anyway if theres a change its better to sync it..

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in my plist; for me the issue was an `&` in a `<string>` value.

My fix was to escape `&` with `&amp;` in my plist. (`&` needs to be escaped in XML)

Background on my issue: I'm storing escaped HTML as string values in my plist, escaping `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. But there were URLs in my HTML with the `&` char that needed to be escaped as well.